# How can I use digikam instead of shotwell in the dash?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, unity, unity-dash

How can I use digikam instead of shotwell in the dash? I cannot choose my preferred photo app in the "Preferred Applications" dialog.

Comment: I know that with almost anything else opening up preferred applications works, but a picture app selector doesn't come up. Strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant currently, see:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/708479/comments/3
and:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/730623/comments/4